# Push unique keys only to array in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I want to build a simple smart contract that is able to create assets and add users with different roles to them. Each user should only be able to have one role at the time per asset assigned.

Code in solidity:

```
contract AccessManagement {

struct Authorization {
    string role;
    bool active;
}

struct Asset {
    address owner;
    address[] authorizationList;
    mapping(address => Authorization) authorizationStructs;
    bool initialized;    
}

mapping(string => Asset) assetStructs;
string[] assetList;

function newAsset(string assetKey) public returns(bool success) {
    // Check for duplicates
    assetStructs[assetKey].owner = msg.sender;
    assetStructs[assetKey].initialized = true;
    assetList.push(assetKey);
    return true;
} 

function addAuthorization(string assetKey, address authorizationKey, string authorizationRole) public returns(bool success) {
    // ??? - Require Role "Admin"
    // ??? - Push only if "authorizationKey" is unique. Otherwise change the values.
    assetStructs[assetKey].authorizationList.push(authorizationKey);
    assetStructs[assetKey].authorizationStructs[authorizationKey].role = authorizationRole;
    assetStructs[assetKey].authorizationStructs[authorizationKey].active = true;
    return true;
}
function getAssetAuthorization(string assetKey, address authorizationKey) public constant returns(string authorizationRole) {
    return(assetStructs[assetKey].authorizationStructs[authorizationKey].role);
}
}
```

My questions regarding this:

- How can I make sure that "authorizationKey" are pushed to authorizationList[] if it is unique? If it is not unique, only the values should be changed.
- How can I check if "assetStructs[assetKey].authorizationStructs[msg.sender].role" is
  equal to admin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you using the authorization list anywhere. You could remove it. To make sure that there is always only one authorization key, you could use the existing map. An existing entry would be overwritten.
When you want to know if the key exists, check for `active` to be `true`, as it will be `false` by default for all non-existing keys.
Do you need to iterate over all addresses at some point?

To check if the role is equal to Admin, I would create an [Enum](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#enums) for the roles and compare against that. Something like this:

```
// Enum
enum Roles { User, Admin };

// Struct
struct Authorization {
    Roles role;
    bool active;
}

// Checking
if (assetStructs[assetKey].authorizationStructs[authorizationKey].role == Roles.Admin) {
    // something here
}
```